# Help with css and jquery grid

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

Im trying to add jquery grid to my site. (codeigniter php)

It loads the data just fine but the grid ends up looking awful.. I dont know much about css....
heres an image of what Im getting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ick. Did you include `ui.jqgrid.css` in your page?

Also, you can use firebug to inspect the various jqGrid elements on your page - it is unlikely but perhaps there is a conflict between the your application's CSS and the CSS used by jqGrid?

Comment: Thats exactly the case.... I deleted (with firebug) the two sidebars and the grid showed up just fine... heres the template Im using
http://www.freecsstemplate.net/template-preview/template21.html

Any ideas on how I can get it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Put the grid in a div with width and overflow:hidden:

```
<div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;">
</div>
```

Example:

```
<div style="width:25%;float:left;background-color:yellow;">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec est ipsum, condimentum non bibendum nec, viverra nec nulla. 
    </p>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:25%;background-color:green;">
    <div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden">
        <div style="clear:both;">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec est ipsum, condimentum non bibendum nec, viverra nec nulla. 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See also: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/03/clearing_floats.html